# RNN and LSTM give low accuracy compared to dense layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16np3KgLfxnjWdxRexyB77sXHMSrhbaoG?usp=sharing is the link to my code-labs.

Graphs:

LSTM

[image: lstm graph]

RNN

[image: rnn graph]

Dense

[image: Dense graph]

All the imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, SimpleRNN, LSTM, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Accuracy
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import reuters
from tensorflow.keras import models, Input
```

I think I'm not missing anything with the input data, it's vectorized. And the output, the tags are encoded using one_hot encoding implementation included in keras...

```
maxFeatures = 8982
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data,test_labels) = reuters.load_data(num_words = maxFeatures, skip_top=0) 
import numpy as np
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=maxFeatures):
results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
    results[i,sequence] = 1.
return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

y_train = to_categorical(train_labels)
y_test = to_categorical(test_labels)
```

Shape of data:

Train data shape: (8982, 8982) and train labels shape: (8982, 46)

Test data shape: (2246, 8982) and test labels shape: (2246, 46)

When using LSTM or Simple RNN I can't get the val_accuracy over ~35 %. I've tried changing the variables, adding different activation layers, and added the dropout in case it was overfitting. I don't think it's under-fitting. Using different activation layers did change it by 1-2%.

```
modelRNN = Sequential()
modelRNN.add(Input(shape=(maxFeatures,)))

modelRNN.add(Embedding(maxFeatures,64))
modelRNN.add(LSTM(64))
modelRNN.add(Dropout(0.2))
modelRNN.add(Dense(46, activation="softmax"))


modelRNN.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

historyRNN = modelRNN.fit(x_train, y_train,
  epochs=10,
  batch_size=256,
  validation_split=0.2
  )
```

Results for RNN model:
[image: Results RNN]

Using the evaluate method with the test data does give me a different percentage of accuracy, but close to 35%.

```
modelRNN.evaluate(x_test,y_test)

71/71 [==============================] - 9s 122ms/step - loss: 2.4143 - accuracy: 0.3620
[2.4142708778381348, 0.36197686195373535]
```

Now for the interesting part: using dense layers gives me a val_accuracy of over 75%. And evaluating the model gives me again over 75%.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(maxFeatures,)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
loss='categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Results after fitting:
[image: Dense fitting results]

I THINK it's something to do with the data, but I'm not sure what.

It might also have something to do with the optimizer I'm using. I've tried both rmsprop and adam with virtually the same results. So maybe it's some other variable that I've left at default.

I'm using softmax as the last layer in all cases, so that I can get the probability for each tag. Might be a activation layer issue? For example in embedding, but testing it with what I know hasn't changed the results.

Answer (score 1):

You are feeding one hot vectors to Embedding layer. You should feed integer indices instead. Don't call `vectorize_sequence()`. Create a dictionary of tokens and tokenize you sequences. E.g. if you have a sequence "my sequence my sequence" - you should feed [0, 1, 0, 1] to the network, not [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]].

Comment: My data is text, and the output is 46 tags. So it should work..